# How to represent/structure Excel table data to get Quarterly Chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

[image]

I need to create chart similar to this one. anybody here to tell me, in order to get this kind of graph output, how Excel table data can be represented/structured?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up the data like this:

[image: Data for Column-Line Chart]

The block in  the top left is for the clustered columns. The column on the right is for the line. The blank cells will produce the gaps between the clusters, while the blanks at the top and bottom will make the spacing work out right.

Select the first block of data and insert a clustered column chart. You will probably have to switch rows and columns: Excel created a chart with years along the axis and quarters in the legend. This is the top left view below.

Select and copy the single column of data, including the blank cells at the top and bottom. Select the chart, and use Paste Special (Home tab > Paste dropdown), and use the settings in the top right view below: New Series and By Columns in the top, nothing checked below.

The chart looks like you broke it, bottom left view below, but hang in there, we're going to fix it.

Select the added series (if you have to, select another series and click the up arrow until you've selected it). Press Ctrl+1 to format it, and in the formatting dialog/taskpane, choose Secondary axis. Now it shows up, see bottom right view below.

[image: Starting to Build the Column-Line Chart]

Okay, we're still fixing it. We need a secondary horizontal axis. In Excel 2013-2016, click the plus icon next to the chart, and make sure all four axes are checked. In Excel 2007-2010, find the controls for this on the Chart Tools > Layout tab. Now the data almost lines up, top left view below.

Right click on the added series, choose Change Series Chart Type, and choose the line with markers option, top right view below.

Now there's just some cleanup. Double click on one of the bar series, and on the formatting dialog/taskpane, change Gap Width to 100 and Overlap to zero. Double click the top X axis, Under Axis Tick Labels, choose None, and for Axis Position, choose On Tick Marks. Et voila, bottom left view below. I forgot, but you can remove the extra line entry from the legend easily enough: click once to select the legend, click again to select the legend entry, and press Delete.

[image: Finishing up the Column-Line Chart]